# Fetching Multiple Different Entities from the same Core Data Database

Tags: ios, entity-framework, core-data

I am implementing an application where I have a bunch of different Entities which I inherit from a base model that is common to all these entities.  Currently Lets say I have EntityParent who is my base class and I have about 5 different Entities inheriting the base class.  Lets say I have EntityA, EntityB, EntityC, EntityD and EntityE respectively and currently I am fetching EntityA from the database and I also would like to fetch other entities just like Below:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = _managedObjectContext;

NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription* entityDiscA = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityA" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entityDiscA];

NSError* error;

NSArray *fetchedAs = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


NSFetchRequest * fetchRequestB = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription* entityDiscB = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityB" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequestB setEntity:entityDiscB];

NSError* error;

NSArray *fetchedBs = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestB error:&error];
```

But I would like to also fetch EntityB's and EntityC's and so forth, but when I try to fetch my app crashes. If you look at the above code, when I try to fetch the EntityB, I get a SigAbort and crashes. Whats wrong with the code snippet above?  Are we not allowed to fetch multiple different Entities using Core Data?  Is my only option is to just fetch all the objects based on the parent class and then filter using the class name?  I would prefer not to do that, but if thats the only way out, I guess I would have to suck up and work with it.  Would appreciate any suggestions or tips (I did read one of the posts where the person suggests to declare the parent class as abstract entity and use it to do fetches)

Thanks,
Rajan

Comment: You have to tell us what the error is, otherwise there is no way to know what is not working.

Comment: I am getting Sig Abort just when I execute the second fetch statement.

Comment: Just edited with more information :)

Comment: What does the `error` object say?

Comment: Found my problem.  Had a typo on the Entity name that I was trying to fetch.  It works fine once I corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fetch all the entities one by one. You can simply loop.

```
NSMutableArray *allOfThem = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *entitySuffix in @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E"]) {
   NSString *entity = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"Entity", entitySuffix];
   NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entity];
   [allOfThem addObjectsFromArray:
      [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil]];
}
```

Make sure that all the entity names are correct before creating the fetch request.

Comment: Although this is not what I was looking for, but after double checking I found a typo in the Entity names and my original code works just fine the way I wanted after fixing the typo.  Thanks for the suggestion.