# CoreData : Fetch Multiple Entities using NSFetchedResultController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I can fetch one entity and display the data in a tableview with single section using `NSFetchedResultsController`. But how to fetch two or more entities (no relation) using `NSFetchedResultsController` and display the data in different section?

I noticed that using core data, I can get number of section and number of row using `NSFetchedResultsController`. I set one entity in `NSFetchedResultsController` and it handles `tableView` very well including add and delete row.

```js
func getFetchedResultController() - > NSFetchedResultsController {
  fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
  fetchedResultController.delegate = self
  fetchedResultController.performFetch(nil)
  return fetchedResultController
}

func fetchRequest() - > NSFetchRequest {
  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Fruits")
  let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "desc", ascending: true)
  fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
  return fetchRequest
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) - > Int {
  let section = fetchedResultController.sections ? .count
  return section!
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) - > Int {
  if let s = fetchedResultController.sections as ? [NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo] {
    return s[section].numberOfObjects
  }
  return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) - > UITableViewCell {
  var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
  let fruit = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Fruits
  cell.textLabel.text = fruit.desc
  return cell
}
```

But section always zero because it only uses one entity. Let say I want to show 2 entities/tables Fruits and Drinks (no relation), where should I put these entities in my code above? Can `NSFetchedResultsController` handles these entities in different section in `tableView`?

Comment: I found another way to do this, I read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337326/fetching-multiple-different-entities-from-the-same-core-data-database) but if NSFetchedResultController can do the same thing, I like to try. Is it possible and how?

Comment: For info : If you have just started your project, you should try Realm : http://realm.io . Realm is very easy to use and abstract a lot of heavy code. Less code code for same performances. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **two** `fetchedResultsControllers`, say `fruitFRC` and `drinksFRC`, and then map the `indexPath` reported by those FRCs to the `indexPath` used by the tableView.  For example, if fruit are to appear in section 0 of the tableView, you can just use the tableView `indexPath` to lookup in the `fruitFRC` to get the fruit details.  But for drinks, in section 1 of the tableView, you need to create a new `indexPath` since the `drinksFRC` will be using section 0.  (You can use `indexPathForRow:inSection:` method of `NSIndexPath` to create the new indexPath.)

Likewise, in `numberOfRowsInSection`, if the `section` is 0, return the number of objects in `fruitFRC`, and if the `section` is 1, return the number of objects in `drinksFRC`.

And so on...

Comment: So that means there is no way I can use one NSFetchedResultController to fetch multiple entities to simplify my code? thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: Basically, that's right - a fetch or fetchedResultController will retrieve only one entity type.  But if the Fruit and Drink entities have a lot of attributes in common, I guess you could define them as separate subentities of a single parent entity ("Food"?), and fetch the parent entity.  But that would probably be more complex than the  two FRC solution.